# Can't Change DataGridViewCell type

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to convert a cell (Most cells are populated with information) but when I get this column from the database its NULL. 
In the `datagridview` it shows as nothing. This cell is type is `DateTime` but what I want to do is:
If that cell is `NULL` I want to change that to `N/A` but when I put these two lines of code in:

```
userDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[column] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
userDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[column].Value = "N/A";
```

And run I get a run time error saying `Can't assign N/A to DateTime.` How do I fix this?

Comment: How does the userDataGridView get populated?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
if (userDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[column].Value == null || userDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[column].Value.ToString() == "")
                        {
                            userDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[column].Value = userDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[column].Value.ToString().Replace("", "N/A");
                        }
```

This will check if cell is null then replace that with N/A. But this is not advisable because db value is `DateTime` which will cause problems in the future if you fail to convert it properly. So if you pull a null value from db then you can show it as `N/A` but when it gets stored back to db it should be converted back to `null` or an actual `DateTime`.

Comment: You can't check for `.ToString() == null` this itself will cause a null reference exception, assuming the object `.Value` is null itself. You need to check the object for a null reference `.Value == null`

Comment: Oops my bad. Forgot about that. Thanks @MickIlovski. Editing code above.